# Style error for an app with SASS

Tags: angular

I created a new app in angular 4 (no special flags).
npm installed, build and served. the app runs ok.

Since I want to use SASS in my app, I created another app with the SASS flag i.e.

```
ng new myApp --style SASS
```

After building and serving locally, I get the following error:

**Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings**

Comment: I think it should be --style=scss

Comment: It works -thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same issue I was having with --style only with scss.
Version 1.4.3 of the CLI no longer lists --style as an option under --help, but the suggestion from the version 1.27 help under the style option "You can later change the value in ".angular-cli.json" (defaults.styleExt)." seems to work (any other ccs file can also be renamed if references to them are also edited).  I also renamed the styles.css file styles.scss and made the corresponding change to styles in the .angular-cli.json file.